# Unable to run play application using sbt Tests.setup for integration testing

Tags: playframework, sbt, integration-testing

I want to run my integration tests over play.test.TestServer. So all tests will be just sending Http requests to TestServer and asserting the Http results.

However if I start TestServer in the @BeforeClass method test suite, it takes so much time to run all integration tests since I need to start and stop play server for each suite.

So I decided to start play test server using sbt's Tests.Setup method

```
Tests.Setup(loader=>   
    loader.loadClass("it.PlayTestRunner")
       .getMethod("startup")
       .invoke(null)
)
```

I am able to call startup method but it throws below exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tyrex.naming.MemoryContextFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:72)
at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:61)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:672)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
at play.api.libs.JNDI$.initialContext$lzycompute(JNDI.scala:40)
at play.api.libs.JNDI$.initialContext(JNDI.scala:22)
at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:63)
```

I guess this problem is related with classloading JNDI objects.

Do you know any idea to overcome this problem?

Comment: Please add your answer and accept it since it solves your problem. For now your question seems to be unanswered.

Comment: Ah sorry, done it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. JNDI uses thread's context class loader to load the required classes but sbt's thread context class loader is not set correctly. So updating the code as below solved my problem;

```
Tests.Setup(loader=>{
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader) 
    loader.loadClass("it.PlayTestRunner")
       .getMethod("startup")
       .invoke(null)
})
```